# how to upload profile image to user_auth seperately using OnetoOneField() in python django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

```
CAMROID
|--accounts_app
|    |--admin.py
|    |--models.py
|    |--urls.py
|    |--views.py
|
|--camroid_app
|    |--admin.py
|    |--models.py
|    |--urls.py
|    |--views.py
|
|--camroid_project
|    |--settings.py
|    |--urls.py
|
|--media
|    |--ProfileImg
|
|--static
|    |--css
|    |--js
|    |--fonts
|    |--images
|
|--templates
     |--base.html
     |--category.html
     |--index.html
     |--myspace.html
     |--register.html
```

I have a sign up form from where a user can register and his details is uploaded to `user_auth` table and in addition to that there is another model `UserProfile` which contains `profile_img = Imagefield()` has a `OnetoOneField` relation to `user_auth` table and a user can only upload his profile image when he sign in. So a user is not uploading image while he register and can only upload profile image from myspace.html.

`accounts_app` handles all accounts related functionality like register and sign in and
`camroid_app` handles the actual content of the site [index.html, myspace.html]

[here is myspace.html page. As you can see i'm using two seperate form one for uploading profile pic and another for updating details of user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5itjy.png)

form for updating details will be an easy task but for uploading profile pic while working with `OnetoOneField` is where i need help. As i don't know how it works. I have already gone through most of the solutions but in all examples user is uploading image from django admin application while creating a user. But i have a different senario, i want the user to upload image from main application and not from django admin application, plus image can only be uploaded when the user is already created.

`models.py`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfileImg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

`views.py`

```
        request.POST['action'] == 'save-upload':

            if request.FILES['profile-upload'] != None:
                userprofilemodel = apps.get_model('accounts_app', 'UserProfile')

                profile_img = request.FILES['profile-upload']

              /// your suggested code
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put related name in the onetoonefield like that and after that you can get the userprofile image url like this

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfileImg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

after that use like this

```
user_object.profile.profile_img
```

and if you dont want to put related name then you can use like this

```
user_object.user.profile_img
```

i am not sure about second method but first will run

Comment: i don't unserstand where i need to use this code. can you please explain it. I have updated my code. I' posting my ```views.py``` code

Comment: my bad sorry for that but actually you have to take foreign key fot that because using one to one field you can only make one model of UserProfile per User and if you really want one profile then you have to again take foreign key on profile_img = models.ForeignKay(Image) and make another model for image

Comment: I think, OnetoOneField allow one row of one table link corresponding to single row of another table. and that is what i want. foreign key will create a one to many relation, and i don't think i need that

Comment: If you need one image per one user then its right so now you have to do some chages in the view now ok ill give you a proper soln at 8 if anyone dont answer then.